# Android kotlin handler and coroutine launch(IO) combination not working

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, android-handler

My collegeus used this code in the app which caused huge bug and crash:

```
fun submitBonusDecision(decision: Boolean, bonusIdentifier: String) = viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {

        clientService.submitBonusDecision(decision, bonusIdentifier).getResult(
            success = {
                val handler = Handler()

                handler.postDelayed(
                    {
                        viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
                            clientManager.refreshClientStatus()
                        }
                    },
                    7000
                )
            }
        )
    }
```

When I remove the launch part (coroutines), this code works fine. I would like to have a nice and long explanation of why is this happening. I know Handler uses a single thread, and that launch launches a new coroutine that runs outside of the main thread.
Is it possible that the handler's ability to communicate back with the main thread (and we use dispatchers.IO in coroutines) has something to do with this? Thanks

Here is the stack trace:

```
2021-11-14 01:47:01.151 29571-29662/fortuna.vegas.android.ro D/OkHttp: strict-transport-security: max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains
2021-11-14 01:47:01.151 29571-29662/fortuna.vegas.android.ro D/OkHttp: cf-cache-status: DYNAMIC
2021-11-14 01:47:01.151 29571-29662/fortuna.vegas.android.ro D/OkHttp: expect-ct: max-age=604800, report-uri="https://report-uri.cloudflare.com/cdn-cgi/beacon/expect-ct"
2021-11-14 01:47:01.151 29571-29662/fortuna.vegas.android.ro D/OkHttp: server: cloudflare
2021-11-14 01:47:01.151 29571-29662/fortuna.vegas.android.ro D/OkHttp: cf-ray: 6adc39e32ae8fcf9-OTP
2021-11-14 01:47:01.153 29571-29662/fortuna.vegas.android.ro D/OkHttp: [{"controlType":"USER_STATUS"},{"controlType":"IMAGE_CAROUSEL","content":[{"url":"ftnvegasro://browser?url=https%3A%2F%2Fcasino.efortuna.ro%2Fleaderboard-games-2&transferSession=true","pictureId":"618d3aa82cb91d0a26a1604f"},{"url":"ftnvegasro://categories/5f562bb853410c11ca42c4e9","pictureId":"614c854a56b07253c4290704"},{"url":"ftnvegasro://categories/614d96f356b07253c4290ab5","pictureId":"6151c63656b07253c42912e7"},{"url":"ftnvegasro://browser?url=https%3A%2F%2Fcasino.efortuna.ro%2Fpromotions%2F67646&transferSession=true","pictureId":"614b59bf56b07253c4290480"},{"url":"ftnvegasro://browser?url=https%3A%2F%2Fcasino.efortuna.ro%2F&transferSession=true","pictureId":"6108f7d589a93514dd40cd70"},{"url":"ftnvegasro://browser?url=https%3A%2F%2Fcasino.efortuna.ro%2Fmy-account%2Fdeposit&transferSession=true","pictureId":"610d8ec689a93514dd40d6f8"},{"url":"ftnvegasro://games/5f438e56aef0d83dfce1b9c4","pictureId":"5f96841ed136442a74a68761"},{"url":"ftnvegasro://browser?url=https%3A%2F%2Fm.efortuna.ro%2Floto%23%2F&transferSession=true","pictureId":"5f96cf77d136442a74a6886b"},{"url":"ftnvegasro://games/5f56245c53410c11ca42c4cf","pictureId":"5f9683ddd136442a74a68756"}]},{"controlType":"GAME_CATEGORY","name":"Top Jocuri","categoryId":"5f91559bd136442a74a67f07","hasMore":true,"content":[{"id":"5f4f624953410c11ca42c0c8","gameCode":"pop_7271_egtifo","urlType":"vegas_native_EGT_REAL","verticalThumbnailId":"5f6b3747eaaa8171094d2381","nativeGame":false},{"id":"5f437a7baef0d83dfce1b961","gameCode":"aogs","urlType":"vegas_native_PLAYTECH_REAL","verticalThumbnailId":"5f75d929d136442a74a645cc","nativeGame":true},{"id":"5f56245c53410c11ca42c4cf","gameCode":"pop_11974_grtifo","urlType":"vegas_native_NOVOMATIC_REAL","verticalThumbnailId":"5f57859c53410c11ca42cd4a","nativeGame":false},{"id":"5f578f0a53410c11ca42ce75","gameCode":"pop_12116_sntifo","urlType":"vegas_native_SYNOT_REAL","verticalThumbnailId":"5f58ac8553410c11ca42d2e6","nativeGame":false},{"id":"5f438926aef0d83dfce1b9a9","gameCode":"aogrots","urlType":"vegas_native_PLAYTECH_REAL","verticalThumbnailId":"5f86ddaed136442a74a663b0","nativeGame":true},{"id":"5f43810caef0d83dfce1b976","gameCode":"bfb","urlType":"vegas_native_PLAYTECH_REAL","verticalThumbnailId":"5f60c53a53410c11ca42e197","nativeGame":true},{"id":"5f4f54c053410c11ca42c091","gameCode":"pop_7254_egtifo","urlType":"vegas_native_EGT_REAL","verticalThumbnailId":"5f57683e53410c11ca42cb98","nativeGame":false},{"id":"5f43ad34aef0d83dfce1b9e0","gameCode":"pop_10507_egtifo","urlType":"vegas_native_EGT_REAL","verticalThumbnailId":"5f574fe153410c11ca42ca9e","nativeGame":false},{"id":"5f562a8153410c11ca42c4e4","gameCode":"pop_11442_grtifo","urlType":"vegas_native_NOVOMATIC_REAL","verticalThumbnailId":"5f57891453410c11ca42ce45","nativeGame":false},{"id":"5f43ada1aef0d83dfce1b9e4","gameCode":"pop_7255_egtifo","urlType":"vegas_native_EGT_REAL","verticalThumbnailId":"5f57511253410c11ca42cb21","nativeGame":false}]},{"controlType":"GAME_CATEGORY","name":"Jocuri Noi","categoryId":"5f91584cd136442a74a67f17","hasMore":true,"content":[{"id":"618d411b2cb91d0a26a16094","gameCode":"gpas_wtrack_pop","urlType":"vegas_native_GPAS_REAL","verticalThumbnailId":"618d410b2cb91d0a26a16081","nativeGame":false},{"id":"618d419f2cb91d0a26a160b4","gameCode":"pop_swbd_skw","urlType":"vegas_native_SKYWIND_REAL","verticalThumbnailId":"618d418e2cb91d0a26a1609e","nativeGame":false},{"id":"618a80d22cb91d0a26a15b3b","gameCode":"pop_41d189af_pngifo","urlType":"vegas_native_PLAYNGO_REAL","verticalThumbnailId":"618a80c32cb91d0a26a15b26","nativeGame":false},{"id":"618a814b2cb91d0a26a15b59","gameCode":"pop_6683aaac_skw","urlType":"vegas_native_SKYWIND_REAL","verticalThumbnailId":"618a81342cb91d0a26a15b44","nativeGame":false},{"id":"6183a9e0cdaf5d3406c339d2","gameCode":"pop_5e96ba2f_pngifo","urlType":"vegas_native_PLAYNGO_REAL","verticalThumbnailId":"6183a9cfcdaf5d3406c339b9","nativeGame":false},{"id":"6183aa2ecdaf5d3406c339f2","gameCode":"pop_3d503ba3_skw","urlType":"vegas_native_SKYWI
2021-11-14 01:47:01.153 29571-29662/fortuna.vegas.android.ro D/OkHttp: ND_REAL","verticalThumbnailId":"6183aa1ecdaf5d3406c339db","nativeGame":false},{"id":"618115bfcdaf5d3406c33483","gameCode":"gpas_wpanda_pop","urlType":"vegas_native_GPAS_REAL","verticalThumbnailId":"618115b0cdaf5d3406c33470","nativeGame":false},{"id":"61811653cdaf5d3406c334a1","gameCode":"pop_e5f570a5_skw","urlType":"vegas_native_SKYWIND_REAL","verticalThumbnailId":"61811638cdaf5d3406c3348c","nativeGame":false},{"id":"617b9a43cdaf5d3406c32aaa","gameCode":"pop_9429_pngifo","urlType":"vegas_native_PLAYNGO_REAL","verticalThumbnailId":"617b9a35cdaf5d3406c32a95","nativeGame":false},{"id":"617b99b7cdaf5d3406c32a8c","gameCode":"pop_6fbb2598_skw","urlType":"vegas_native_SKYWIND_REAL","verticalThumbnailId":"617b99a2cdaf5d3406c32a77","nativeGame":false}]},{"controlType":"ALL_CATEGORIES","content":[{"id":"5f917dcad136442a74a67f3d","name":"Jackpoturi"},{"id":"5f562bb853410c11ca42c4e9","name":"EGT"},{"id":"5f4f66e653410c11ca42c0d7","name":"Novomatic"},{"id":"5f43aa8eaef0d83dfce1b9db","name":"Apollo"},{"id":"5f5637af53410c11ca42c4f7","name":"Synot"},{"id":"5f56339653410c11ca42c4eb","name":"NetEnt"},{"id":"5f51f07d53410c11ca42c278","name":"Kajot"},{"id":"614d96f356b07253c4290ab5","name":"Skywind"},{"id":"6152e8ed56b07253c429170f","name":"Play'n GO"},{"id":"602b9108bc5f8a42c1224b76","name":"Yggdrasil"},{"id":"5f438ddfaef0d83dfce1b9c3","name":"Playtech"},{"id":"5f577c7453410c11ca42cd40","name":"LIVE Casino"},{"id":"5f91559bd136442a74a67f07","name":"Top Jocuri"},{"id":"5f91584cd136442a74a67f17","name":"Jocuri Noi"},{"id":"5f9692dfd136442a74a687a4","name":"Jocuri de masa"}]},{"controlType":"FOOTER"}]
2021-11-14 01:47:01.153 29571-29662/fortuna.vegas.android.ro D/OkHttp: <-- END HTTP (5607-byte body)
2021-11-14 01:47:01.167 29571-29655/fortuna.vegas.android.ro D/Surface: Surface::connect(this=0x7d7592b000,api=1)
2021-11-14 01:47:01.168 29571-29655/fortuna.vegas.android.ro D/mali_winsys: EGLint new_window_surface(egl_winsys_display *, void *, EGLSurface, EGLConfig, egl_winsys_surface **, EGLBoolean) returns 0x3000
2021-11-14 01:47:01.168 29571-29655/fortuna.vegas.android.ro D/Surface: Surface::setBufferCount(this=0x7d7592b000,bufferCount=3)
2021-11-14 01:47:01.168 29571-29655/fortuna.vegas.android.ro D/Surface: Surface::allocateBuffers(this=0x7d7592b000)
2021-11-14 01:47:01.297 29571-29571/fortuna.vegas.android.ro W/Looper: Slow Looper main: doFrame is 341ms late because of 4 msg, msg 1 took 359ms (seq=247 running=221ms runnable=2ms io=39ms late=15ms h=android.view.Choreographer$FrameHandler c=android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver)
2021-11-14 01:47:01.309 29571-29662/fortuna.vegas.android.ro D/OkHttp: --> GET https://m.efortuna.ro/api/v4_7_0/playerStatistics
2021-11-14 01:47:01.309 29571-29662/fortuna.vegas.android.ro D/OkHttp: Authorization: fortunapublicapikey:UzSRdHikff0xPnBNd6AULyuPlsl83SJQES2C3i8J1pY=
2021-11-14 01:47:01.309 29571-29662/fortuna.vegas.android.ro D/OkHttp: --> END GET
2021-11-14 01:47:01.325 29571-29571/fortuna.vegas.android.ro D/ForceDarkHelper: updateByCheckExcludeList: pkg: fortuna.vegas.android.ro activity: fortuna.vegas.android.presentation.main.MainActivity@8d09473
2021-11-14 01:47:01.326 29571-29811/fortuna.vegas.android.ro I/System.out: [OkHttp] sendRequest>>
2021-11-14 01:47:01.326 29571-29811/fortuna.vegas.android.ro I/System.out: [OkHttp] sendRequest<<
2021-11-14 01:47:01.326 29571-29571/fortuna.vegas.android.ro D/ForceDarkHelper: updateByCheckExcludeList: pkg: fortuna.vegas.android.ro activity: fortuna.vegas.android.presentation.main.MainActivity@8d09473
2021-11-14 01:47:01.342 29571-29571/fortuna.vegas.android.ro D/ForceDarkHelper: updateByCheckExcludeList: pkg: fortuna.vegas.android.ro activity: fortuna.vegas.android.presentation.main.MainActivity@8d09473
2021-11-14 01:47:01.357 29571-29571/fortuna.vegas.android.ro I/chatty: uid=10379(fortuna.vegas.android.ro) identical 4 lines
2021-11-14 01:47:01.357 29571-29571/fortuna.vegas.android.ro D/ForceDarkHelper: updateByCheckExcludeList: pkg: fortuna.vegas.android.ro activity: fortuna.vegas.android.presentation.main.MainActivity@8d09473
2021-11-14 01:47:01.371 29571-29571/fortuna.vegas.android.ro W/Glide: Failed to find GeneratedAppGlideModule. You should include an annotationProcessor compile dependency on com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler in your application and a @GlideModule annotated AppGlideModule implementation or LibraryGlideModules will be silently ignored
2021-11-14 01:47:01.413 29571-29571/fortuna.vegas.android.ro D/ForceDarkHelper: updateByCheckExcludeList: pkg: fortuna.vegas.android.ro activity: fortuna.vegas.android.presentation.main.MainActivity@8d09473
2021-11-14 01:47:01.437 29571-29571/fortuna.vegas.android.ro I/chatty: uid=10379(fortuna.vegas.android.ro) identical 8 lines
2021-11-14 01:47:01.439 29571-29571/fortuna.vegas.android.ro D/ForceDarkHelper: updateByCheckExcludeList: pkg: fortuna.vegas.android.ro activity: fortuna.vegas.android.presentation.main.MainActivity@8d09473
2021-11-14 01:47:01.447 29571-29811/fortuna.vegas.android.ro W/System.err: SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
2021-11-14 01:47:01.447 29571-29811/fortuna.vegas.android.ro W/System.err: SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
2021-11-14 01:47:01.447 29571-29811/fortuna.vegas.android.ro W/System.err: SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
2021-11-14 01:47:01.457 29571-29825/fortuna.vegas.android.ro I/System.out: [socket]:check permission begin!
2021-11-14 01:47:01.464 29571-29571/fortuna.vegas.android.ro D/ForceDarkHelper: updateByCheckExcludeList: pkg: fortuna.vegas.android.ro activity: fortuna.vegas.android.presentation.main.MainActivity@8d09473
2021-11-14 01:47:01.469 29571-29571/fortuna.vegas.android.ro I/chatty: uid=10379(fortuna.vegas.android.ro) identical 5 lines
2021-11-14 01:47:01.469 29571-29571/fortuna.vegas.android.ro D/ForceDarkHelper: updateByCheckExcludeList: pkg: fortuna.vegas.android.ro activity: fortuna.vegas.android.presentation.main.MainActivity@8d09473
2021-11-14 01:47:01.494 29571-29571/fortuna.vegas.android.ro D/ForceDarkHelper: updateByCheckExcludeList: pkg: fortuna.vegas.android.ro activity: fortuna.vegas.android.presentation.main.MainActivity@8d09473
2021-11-14 01:47:01.539 29571-29571/fortuna.vegas.android.ro I/chatty: uid=10379(fortuna.vegas.android.ro) identical 17 lines
2021-11-14 01:47:01.541 29571-29571/fortuna.vegas.android.ro D/ForceDarkHelper: updateByCheckExcludeList: pkg: fortuna.vegas.android.ro activity: fortuna.vegas.android.presentation.main.MainActivity@8d09473
2021-11-14 01:47:01.541 29571-29662/fortuna.vegas.android.ro D/OkHttp: <-- 401 https://m.efortuna.ro/api/v4_7_0/playerStatistics (232ms)
2021-11-14 01:47:01.541 29571-29662/fortuna.vegas.android.ro D/OkHttp: date: Sun, 14 Nov 2021 00:47:02 GMT
2021-11-14 01:47:01.541 29571-29662/fortuna.vegas.android.ro D/OkHttp: content-type: text/plain;charset=UTF-8
2021-11-14 01:47:01.542 29571-29662/fortuna.vegas.android.ro D/OkHttp: content-length: 35
2021-11-14 01:47:01.542 29571-29662/fortuna.vegas.android.ro D/OkHttp: set-cookie: route=4eff2d734f793077ffbcbacada6c58b1; Domain=m.efortuna.ro; Expires=Sun, 14-Nov-2021 12:47:02 GMT; Path=/
2021-11-14 01:47:01.542 29571-29662/fortuna.vegas.android.ro D/OkHttp: vary: Origin
2021-11-14 01:47:01.542 29571-29662/fortuna.vegas.android.ro D/OkHttp: vary: Access-Control-Request-Method
2021-11-14 01:47:01.542 29571-29662/fortuna.vegas.android.ro D/OkHttp: vary: Access-Control-Request-Headers
2021-11-14 01:47:01.542 29571-29662/fortuna.vegas.android.ro D/OkHttp: last-android-version: 3.24.1
2021-11-14 01:47:01.542 29571-29662/fortuna.vegas.android.ro D/OkHttp: last-mandatory-android-version: 3.23.1
2021-11-14 01:47:01.542 29571-29662/fortuna.vegas.android.ro D/OkHttp: last-minimal-supported-android-version: 21
2021-11-14 01:47:01.542 29571-29662/fortuna.vegas.android.ro D/OkHttp: last-ios-version: 36.1
2021-11-14 01:47:01.542 29571-29662/fortuna.vegas.android.ro D/OkHttp: last-mandatory-ios-version: 36.0
2021-11-14 01:47:01.542 29571-29662/fortuna.vegas.android.ro D/OkHttp: last-minimal-supported-ios-version: 10
2021-11-14 01:47:01.542 29571-29662/fortuna.vegas.android.ro D/OkHttp: remaining-limit: -1
2021-11-14 01:47:01.542 29571-29662/fortuna.vegas.android.ro D/OkHttp: x-content-type-options: nosniff
2021-11-14 01:47:01.542 29571-29662/fortuna.vegas.android.ro D/OkHttp: x-xss-protection: 1; mode=block
2021-11-14 01:47:01.542 29571-29662/fortuna.vegas.android.ro D/OkHttp: strict-transport-security: max-age=31536000 ; includeSubDomains
2021-11-14 01:47:01.542 29571-29662/fortuna.vegas.android.ro D/OkHttp: set-cookie: SESSION=MzY2ZmE0NjYtYTg0Zi00NjZjLTk5NDktYjQ1NGNjZTBkNzkx; Path=/; Secure; HttpOnly; SameSite=Lax
2021-11-14 01:47:01.542 29571-29662/fortuna.vegas.android.ro D/OkHttp: x-b3-traceid: 9e6b1f870f0539ab5f978c8753546b12
2021-11-14 01:47:01.542 29571-29662/fortuna.vegas.android.ro D/OkHttp: strict-transport-security: max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains
2021-11-14 01:47:01.542 29571-29662/fortuna.vegas.android.ro D/OkHttp: cf-cache-status: DYNAMIC
2021-11-14 01:47:01.542 29571-29662/fortuna.vegas.android.ro D/OkHttp: expect-ct: max-age=604800, report-uri="https://report-uri.cloudflare.com/cdn-cgi/beacon/expect-ct"
2021-11-14 01:47:01.542 29571-29662/fortuna.vegas.android.ro D/OkHttp: server: cloudflare
2021-11-14 01:47:01.542 29571-29662/fortuna.vegas.android.ro D/OkHttp: cf-ray: 6adc39e54c32fcf9-OTP
2021-11-14 01:47:01.543 29571-29571/fortuna.vegas.android.ro D/ForceDarkHelper: updateByCheckExcludeList: pkg: fortuna.vegas.android.ro activity: fortuna.vegas.android.presentation.main.MainActivity@8d09473
2021-11-14 01:47:01.545 29571-29662/fortuna.vegas.android.ro D/OkHttp: {"errorText":"User not logged in!"}
2021-11-14 01:47:01.545 29571-29662/fortuna.vegas.android.ro D/OkHttp: <-- END HTTP (35-byte body)
2021-11-14 01:47:01.550 29571-29826/fortuna.vegas.android.ro D/DRM/DcfDecoder: decodeDrmImageIfNeeded with stream left [34241]
2021-11-14 01:47:01.550 29571-29826/fortuna.vegas.android.ro E/DRM/DcfDecoder: decodeDrmImageIfNeeded stream caught ClassCastException 
2021-11-14 01:47:01.563 29571-29571/fortuna.vegas.android.ro D/ForceDarkHelper: updateByCheckExcludeList: pkg: fortuna.vegas.android.ro activity: fortuna.vegas.android.presentation.main.MainActivity@8d09473
2021-11-14 01:47:01.564 29571-29571/fortuna.vegas.android.ro D/ForceDarkHelper: updateByCheckExcludeList: pkg: fortuna.vegas.android.ro activity: fortuna.vegas.android.presentation.main.MainActivity@8d09473
2021-11-14 01:47:01.565 29571-29571/fortuna.vegas.android.ro D/ForceDarkHelper: updateByCheckExcludeList: pkg: fortuna.vegas.android.ro activity: fortuna.vegas.android.presentation.main.MainActivity@8d09473
2021-11-14 01:47:01.582 29571-29571/fortuna.vegas.android.ro I/chatty: uid=10379(fortuna.vegas.android.ro) identical 9 lines
2021-11-14 01:47:01.583 29571-29571/fortuna.vegas.android.ro D/ForceDarkHelper: updateByCheckExcludeList: pkg: fortuna.vegas.android.ro activity: fortuna.vegas.android.presentation.main.MainActivity@8d09473
2021-11-14 01:47:01.583 29571-29826/fortuna.vegas.android.ro D/DRM/DcfDecoder: decodeDrmImageIfNeeded with stream left [171299]
2021-11-14 01:47:01.583 29571-29826/fortuna.vegas.android.ro E/DRM/DcfDecoder: decodeDrmImageIfNeeded stream caught ClassCastException 
2021-11-14 01:47:01.584 29571-29571/fortuna.vegas.android.ro D/ForceDarkHelper: updateByCheckExcludeList: pkg: fortuna.vegas.android.ro activity: fortuna.vegas.android.presentation.main.MainActivity@8d09473
2021-11-14 01:47:01.597 29571-29571/fortuna.vegas.android.ro I/chatty: uid=10379(fortuna.vegas.android.ro) identical 5 lines
2021-11-14 01:47:01.599 29571-29571/fortuna.vegas.android.ro D/ForceDarkHelper: updateByCheckExcludeList: pkg: fortuna.vegas.android.ro activity: fortuna.vegas.android.presentation.main.MainActivity@8d09473
2021-11-14 01:47:01.599 29571-29826/fortuna.vegas.android.ro D/DRM/DcfDecoder: decodeDrmImageIfNeeded with stream left [68167]
2021-11-14 01:47:01.599 29571-29826/fortuna.vegas.android.ro E/DRM/DcfDecoder: decodeDrmImageIfNeeded stream caught ClassCastException 
2021-11-14 01:47:01.600 29571-29571/fortuna.vegas.android.ro D/ForceDarkHelper: updateByCheckExcludeList: pkg: fortuna.vegas.android.ro activity: fortuna.vegas.android.presentation.main.MainActivity@8d09473
2021-11-14 01:47:01.616 29571-29826/fortuna.vegas.android.ro D/DRM/DcfDecoder: decodeDrmImageIfNeeded with stream left [25682]
2021-11-14 01:47:01.617 29571-29826/fortuna.vegas.android.ro E/DRM/DcfDecoder: decodeDrmImageIfNeeded stream caught ClassCastException 
2021-11-14 01:47:01.633 29571-29826/fortuna.vegas.android.ro D/DRM/DcfDecoder: decodeDrmImageIfNeeded with stream left [123296]
2021-11-14 01:47:01.634 29571-29826/fortuna.vegas.android.ro E/DRM/DcfDecoder: decodeDrmImageIfNeeded stream caught ClassCastException 
2021-11-14 01:47:01.656 29571-29826/fortuna.vegas.android.ro D/DRM/DcfDecoder: decodeDrmImageIfNeeded with stream left [126243]
2021-11-14 01:47:01.656 29571-29826/fortuna.vegas.android.ro E/DRM/DcfDecoder: decodeDrmImageIfNeeded stream caught ClassCastException 
2021-11-14 01:47:01.671 29571-29571/fortuna.vegas.android.ro W/Looper: Slow Looper main: doFrame is 348ms late because of 4 msg, msg 1 took 350ms (seq=267 running=325ms runnable=2ms io=2ms late=14ms h=android.view.Choreographer$FrameHandler c=android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver)
2021-11-14 01:47:01.677 29571-29571/fortuna.vegas.android.ro V/AsyncHttpRH: Progress 68 from 1 (6800%)
2021-11-14 01:47:01.678 29571-29826/fortuna.vegas.android.ro D/DRM/DcfDecoder: decodeDrmImageIfNeeded with stream left [59433]
2021-11-14 01:47:01.679 29571-29826/fortuna.vegas.android.ro E/DRM/DcfDecoder: decodeDrmImageIfNeeded stream caught ClassCastException 
2021-11-14 01:47:01.680 29571-29826/fortuna.vegas.android.ro D/skia: SkJpegCodec::onGetPixels +
2021-11-14 01:47:01.688 29571-29826/fortuna.vegas.android.ro D/skia: SkJpegCodec::onGetPixels -
2021-11-14 01:47:01.702 29571-29826/fortuna.vegas.android.ro D/DRM/DcfDecoder: decodeDrmImageIfNeeded with stream left [140162]
2021-11-14 01:47:01.702 29571-29826/fortuna.vegas.android.ro E/DRM/DcfDecoder: decodeDrmImageIfNeeded stream caught ClassCastException 
2021-11-14 01:47:01.703 29571-29826/fortuna.vegas.android.ro D/skia: SkJpegCodec::onGetPixels +
2021-11-14 01:47:01.714 29571-29826/fortuna.vegas.android.ro D/skia: SkJpegCodec::onGetPixels -
2021-11-14 01:47:01.730 29571-29826/fortuna.vegas.android.ro D/DRM/DcfDecoder: decodeDrmImageIfNeeded with stream left [260064]
2021-11-14 01:47:01.730 29571-29826/fortuna.vegas.android.ro E/DRM/DcfDecoder: decodeDrmImageIfNeeded stream caught ClassCastException 
2021-11-14 01:47:01.732 29571-29826/fortuna.vegas.android.ro D/skia: SkJpegCodec::onGetPixels +
2021-11-14 01:47:01.742 29571-29826/fortuna.vegas.android.ro D/skia: SkJpegCodec::onGetPixels -
2021-11-14 01:47:01.752 29571-29825/fortuna.vegas.android.ro I/io.socket: > 3:::{
      "ID":72001,
      "correlationId":5209d027-9ffc-48f8-8d61-4a86f2d70206,
      "deviceId":475f533538aaf3e5,
      "casinoName":"efortuna",
      "clientSkin":"efortuna",
      "clientVersion":"1.3.0",
      "clientType":"casino",
      "clientPlatform":"download",
      "languageCode":"RO"
    }
2021-11-14 01:47:01.758 29571-29825/fortuna.vegas.android.ro I/io.socket: < 1::
2021-11-14 01:47:01.758 29571-29825/fortuna.vegas.android.ro I/System.out: Connection established
2021-11-14 01:47:01.829 29571-29655/fortuna.vegas.android.ro D/Surface: Surface::disconnect(this=0x7d75c8b000,api=1)
2021-11-14 01:47:01.844 29571-29571/fortuna.vegas.android.ro D/LeakCanary: Watching instance of androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerViewModel (androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerViewModel received ViewModel#onCleared() callback) with key 9f781a7d-8bb6-40fc-8574-94316cec5ebf
2021-11-14 01:47:01.844 29571-29571/fortuna.vegas.android.ro D/LeakCanary: Watching instance of fortuna.vegas.android.presentation.splash.SplashViewModel (fortuna.vegas.android.presentation.splash.SplashViewModel received ViewModel#onCleared() callback) with key 27ecaef8-900e-4a1f-9f30-60f1feb79ec7
2021-11-14 01:47:01.844 29571-29571/fortuna.vegas.android.ro D/LeakCanary: Watching instance of leakcanary.internal.ViewModelClearedWatcher (leakcanary.internal.ViewModelClearedWatcher received ViewModel#onCleared() callback) with key db077cf6-f267-48f3-a44f-bc8abb60bfb5
2021-11-14 01:47:01.844 29571-29571/fortuna.vegas.android.ro D/LeakCanary: Watching instance of androidx.lifecycle.ReportFragment (androidx.lifecycle.ReportFragment received Fragment#onDestroy() callback) with key 461ea0f4-b521-486d-87ce-951848e97761
2021-11-14 01:47:01.845 29571-29571/fortuna.vegas.android.ro D/LeakCanary: Watching instance of fortuna.vegas.android.presentation.splash.SplashActivity (fortuna.vegas.android.presentation.splash.SplashActivity received Activity#onDestroy() callback) with key 4f4419c1-c338-4ba7-975c-4c5b5fb4de89
2021-11-14 01:47:01.848 29571-29571/fortuna.vegas.android.ro D/LeakCanary: Watching instance of androidx.loader.app.LoaderManagerImpl$LoaderViewModel (androidx.loader.app.LoaderManagerImpl$LoaderViewModel received ViewModel#onCleared() callback) with key 9fa1d54c-35c8-4a08-a809-127e3ec46b98
2021-11-14 01:47:01.848 29571-29571/fortuna.vegas.android.ro D/LeakCanary: Watching instance of leakcanary.internal.ViewModelClearedWatcher (leakcanary.internal.ViewModelClearedWatcher received ViewModel#onCleared() callback) with key 461e55c9-9928-4d26-9f79-5b1e96c7fae1
2021-11-14 01:47:01.849 29571-29571/fortuna.vegas.android.ro D/LeakCanary: Watching instance of com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.zzc (com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.zzc received Fragment#onDestroy() callback) with key b6d84a2c-17bd-4fef-b5b1-37284367603c
2021-11-14 01:47:01.851 29571-29571/fortuna.vegas.android.ro D/View: [Warning] assignParent to null: this = DecorView@5a9fe7b[SplashActivity]
2021-11-14 01:47:01.857 29571-29571/fortuna.vegas.android.ro D/LeakCanary: Watching instance of com.android.internal.policy.DecorView (com.android.internal.policy.DecorView received View#onDetachedFromWindow() callback) with key b05adcde-45db-427d-b372-e6f09246cab2
2021-11-14 01:47:01.864 29571-29825/fortuna.vegas.android.ro I/io.socket: < 3:::{"data":{"playerCode":421290705,"correlationId":"5209d027-9ffc-48f8-8d61-4a86f2d70206"},"ID":72002}
2021-11-14 01:47:01.864 29571-29825/fortuna.vegas.android.ro I/System.out: Server said: {"data":{"playerCode":421290705,"correlationId":"5209d027-9ffc-48f8-8d61-4a86f2d70206"},"ID":72002}
2021-11-14 01:47:01.864 29571-29825/fortuna.vegas.android.ro I/io.socket: < 3:::{"available":false,"ID":72028}
2021-11-14 01:47:01.865 29571-29825/fortuna.vegas.android.ro I/System.out: Server said: {"available":false,"ID":72028}
2021-11-14 01:47:01.866 29571-29825/fortuna.vegas.android.ro I/io.socket: < 3:::{"ID":72038}
2021-11-14 01:47:01.866 29571-29825/fortuna.vegas.android.ro I/System.out: Server said: {"ID":72038}
2021-11-14 01:47:02.007 29571-29571/fortuna.vegas.android.ro D/ForceDarkHelper: updateByCheckExcludeList: pkg: fortuna.vegas.android.ro activity: fortuna.vegas.android.presentation.main.MainActivity@8d09473
2021-11-14 01:47:02.083 29571-29571/fortuna.vegas.android.ro I/chatty: uid=10379(fortuna.vegas.android.ro) identical 21 lines
2021-11-14 01:47:02.084 29571-29571/fortuna.vegas.android.ro D/ForceDarkHelper: updateByCheckExcludeList: pkg: fortuna.vegas.android.ro activity: fortuna.vegas.android.presentation.main.MainActivity@8d09473
2021-11-14 01:47:02.098 29571-29571/fortuna.vegas.android.ro D/ForceDarkHelper: updateByCheckExcludeList: pkg: fortuna.vegas.android.ro activity: fortuna.vegas.android.presentation.main.MainActivity@8d09473
2021-11-14 01:47:02.138 29571-29571/fortuna.vegas.android.ro I/chatty: uid=10379(fortuna.vegas.android.ro) identical 7 lines
2021-11-14 01:47:02.139 29571-29571/fortuna.vegas.android.ro D/ForceDarkHelper: updateByCheckExcludeList: pkg: fortuna.vegas.android.ro activity: fortuna.vegas.android.presentation.main.MainActivity@8d09473
2021-11-14 01:47:02.154 29571-29571/fortuna.vegas.android.ro D/ForceDarkHelper: updateByCheckExcludeList: pkg: fortuna.vegas.android.ro activity: fortuna.vegas.android.presentation.main.MainActivity@8d09473
2021-11-14 01:47:02.155 29571-29571/fortuna.vegas.android.ro D/ForceDarkHelper: updateByCheckExcludeList: pkg: fortuna.vegas.android.ro activity: fortuna.vegas.android.presentation.main.MainActivity@8d09473
2021-11-14 01:47:04.318 29571-29605/fortuna.vegas.android.ro I/egas.android.r: ProcessProfilingInfo new_methods=12427 is saved saved_to_disk=1 resolve_classes_delay=8000
2021-11-14 01:47:05.398 29571-29571/fortuna.vegas.android.ro D/ForceDarkHelper: updateByCheckExcludeList: pkg: fortuna.vegas.android.ro activity: fortuna.vegas.android.presentation.main.MainActivity@8d09473
2021-11-14 01:47:05.400 29571-29571/fortuna.vegas.android.ro D/ForceDarkHelper: updateByCheckExcludeList: pkg: fortuna.vegas.android.ro activity: fortuna.vegas.android.presentation.main.MainActivity@8d09473
2021-11-14 01:47:05.530 29571-29571/fortuna.vegas.android.ro D/ForceDarkHelper: updateByCheckExcludeList: pkg: fortuna.vegas.android.ro activity: fortuna.vegas.android.presentation.main.MainActivity@8d09473
2021-11-14 01:47:05.531 29571-29826/fortuna.vegas.android.ro D/DRM/DcfDecoder: decodeDrmImageIfNeeded with stream left [75167]
2021-11-14 01:47:05.532 29571-29826/fortuna.vegas.android.ro E/DRM/DcfDecoder: decodeDrmImageIfNeeded stream caught ClassCastException 
2021-11-14 01:47:05.532 29571-29571/fortuna.vegas.android.ro D/ForceDarkHelper: updateByCheckExcludeList: pkg: fortuna.vegas.android.ro activity: fortuna.vegas.android.presentation.main.MainActivity@8d09473
2021-11-14 01:47:05.533 29571-29826/fortuna.vegas.android.ro D/skia: SkJpegCodec::onGetPixels +
2021-11-14 01:47:05.539 29571-29826/fortuna.vegas.android.ro D/skia: SkJpegCodec::onGetPixels -
2021-11-14 01:47:05.948 29571-29623/fortuna.vegas.android.ro V/FA: Inactivity, disconnecting from the service
2021-11-14 01:47:08.153 29571-29623/fortuna.vegas.android.ro V/FA: Connecting to remote service
2021-11-14 01:47:08.156 29571-29623/fortuna.vegas.android.ro V/FA: Recording user engagement, ms: 7264
2021-11-14 01:47:08.162 29571-29623/fortuna.vegas.android.ro D/FA: Connected to remote service
2021-11-14 01:47:08.164 29571-29623/fortuna.vegas.android.ro V/FA: Processing queued up service tasks: 1
2021-11-14 01:47:08.191 29571-29615/fortuna.vegas.android.ro D/TransportRuntime.SQLiteEventStore: Storing event with priority=HIGHEST, name=FIREBASE_CRASHLYTICS_REPORT for destination cct
2021-11-14 01:47:08.235 29571-29615/fortuna.vegas.android.ro D/TransportRuntime.JobInfoScheduler: Scheduling upload for context TransportContext(cct, HIGHEST, MSRodHRwczovL2NyYXNobHl0aWNzcmVwb3J0cy1wYS5nb29nbGVhcGlzLmNvbS92MS9maXJlbG9nL2xlZ2FjeS9iYXRjaGxvZ1xBSXphU3lCcnBTWVQ0RkZMMDlyZUhKaTZIOUZZZGVpU25VVE92Mk0=) with jobId=-956812437 in 10870ms(Backend next call timestamp 1636850839104). Attempt 1
2021-11-14 01:47:08.269 29571-29623/fortuna.vegas.android.ro V/FA: Recording user engagement, ms: 146
2021-11-14 01:47:08.293 29571-29755/fortuna.vegas.android.ro I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 29571 SIG: 9
```

Comment: Could you please edit your question and provide the complete stack trace of your crash?

Comment: ofc just added it

Comment: There is no stack trace there from your app. There are three crashes for `com.microsoft.appcenter`, but they are from an `AsyncTask`.

Comment: I updated it again (together with function) after I reproduced 1 more crash, but it looks pretty same to me as before. I take stack trace from logcat (with verbose option). If there is any better way to take the stack trace tell me and I can do it.

Comment: Take stack trace using the Error filter.  As of now, your stack trace doesn't contain any error logs.

Comment: @ArpitShukla verbose filter in logcat contains all logs including also the error logs. So with this option, we will not get anything more than in the stack trace I pasted here.

Comment: @Kratos The logs don't seem to contain any error stack trace. Without the stack trace its hard to predict the cause of error.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with this code is that you are trying to show a Toast from a background thread which isn't possible. To display a Toast, you **must** be on the main thread.

A quick fix for this can be to switch to main thread, just before showing the Toast.

```kotlin
handler.postDelayed(
    {
        CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
            // Background thread
            withContext(Dispatcher.Main) {
                // UI Thread
                Toast.makeText(applicationContext,"clientManager.refreshClientStatus()" ,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
            // Background Thread
        }
    },
        7000
    )
```

Comment: Hopefully, you aren't using this code directly in your project as creating a `CoroutineScope` inside a `Runnable` isn't a great idea.

Comment: I updated the code where the crash happens (this is code from our app production, it doesn't contain Toast). Yes actually in application this code caused problems. Can you please explain to me why you should not use CoroutineScope or VIewmodelScope inside Runnable?

Comment: 1. If you create your own `CoroutineScope`, you must cancel it at the appropriate time (when it's no longer needed). Not doing so can lead to leaked coroutines. 2. You can use viewModelScope inside Runnable but that's not actually needed. Just use the `delay` function to perform operations after a time delay.

Comment: So what do you think is the direct reason for causing crash and problems in the code above?

Comment: I don't see any obvious reason here, at least not without a proper stack trace of crash.